# Create View Sharing Link for document allows editing of the document

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

The Microsoft Graph [documentation states](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_createlink) that you can create a read-only Sharing Link by setting the `type` property to `view`.

I have tried the same for an Office 365 document in my SharePoint site and have created an organization level edit and view link. However, when I share the view link to another person in my organization, they are able to edit the document.

Am I missing something out here?

Comment: Does that recipient already have access to the SharePoint site?

Comment: Yes both the creator and the recipient has access to the Sharepoint site as it is a Microsoft Teams Site. I also shared the view link to a person who is not a member of the team but part of the organization. Even that user is able to edit the document. What this means is that the view link does not prevent editing?

Comment: Does this happen with any Team in your tenant or only some of them?

Comment: This happens with all the teams in my tenant.

Comment: I would have that user attempt to navigate to the SP Team Site directly and see if they're able to access the file. I suspect the issue here is the site is accessible to that user. If a user has read-write access, a view link won't force it into a read-only view.